# write.table writes unwanted leading empty column to header when has rownames

Tags: r, export-to-csv, write.table

check this example:

```
> a = matrix(1:9, nrow = 3, ncol = 3, dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:3], LETTERS[1:3]))
> a
  A B C
A 1 4 7
B 2 5 8
C 3 6 9
```

the table displays correctly. There are two different ways of writing it to file...

`write.csv(a, 'a.csv')` which gives as expected:

```
"","A","B","C"
"A",1,4,7
"B",2,5,8
"C",3,6,9
```

and `write.table(a, 'a.txt')` which screws up

```
"A" "B" "C"
"A" 1 4 7
"B" 2 5 8
"C" 3 6 9
```

indeed, an empty tab is missing.... which is a pain in the butt for downstream things.
Is this a bug or a feature?
Is there a workaround? (other than `write.table(cbind(rownames(a), a), 'a.txt', row.names=FALSE`)

Cheers,
yannick

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Citing `?write.table`, section **CSV files**:

> By default there is no column name for
>   a column of row names. If `col.names =
>   NA` and `row.names = TRUE` a blank
>   column name is added, which is the
>   convention used for CSV files to be
>   read by spreadsheets.

So you must do

```
write.table(a, 'a.txt', col.names=NA)
```

and you get

```
"" "A" "B" "C"
"A" 1 4 7
"B" 2 5 8
"C" 3 6 9
```

Comment: @Marek, would it be possible to add a name to the rownames column? I.e., instead of "", add "ID" or something alike?

Comment: @Dnaiel From what I know you can't. You may bind row names with data and give them names (as like in question).

Comment: @rusalkaguy Your edit has no point. This "extension" is in original question ("workaround other than")

Comment: How would you get the number in each column to line up under the col names?

Comment: @rrs You mean fixed width format? Look at [write.fwf from gdata package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gdata/versions/2.17.0/topics/write.fwf). And ask new question instead of comment. And why you ever need that?!

Comment: @Marek The write.fwf packages doesn't work. The column names are spaced differently from the column values. I need this because I'm trying to write a GAMS file using R and TABLE columns need to overlap their header.

Comment: @Marek you can use `tibble` to convert rownames to column with a desired ID: `tibble::rownames_to_column(var = "ID")`

Comment: @ÖmerAn Well, tibble was not avaiable at the time when answer was posted ;)

Answer (score 12):

A slight modification to @Marek very helpful answer WILL add a header to the rownames column: temporarily add the rownames as the first column in the data.frame, and write that, ignoring the real rownames.

```
> a = matrix(1:9, nrow = 3, ncol = 3, dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:3], LETTERS[1:3]))
> write.table(data.frame("H"=rownames(a),a),"a.txt", row.names=FALSE)
```

and you get

```
"H" "A" "B" "C"
"A" 1 4 7
"B" 2 5 8
"C" 3 6 9
```

Comment: You should edit Marek's answer to include this, I think.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone working in the [tidyverse](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/09/15/tidyverse-1-0-0/) (dplyr, etc.), the `rownames_to_column()` function from the [tibble](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/radiant.data/versions/0.6.0/topics/rownames_to_column) package can be used to easily convert row.names to a column, e.g.:

```
library('tibble')
a = as.data.frame(matrix(1:9, nrow=3, ncol=3, 
                  dimnames=list(LETTERS[1:3], LETTERS[1:3])))

a %>% rownames_to_column('my_id')

  my_id A B C
1     A 1 4 7
2     B 2 5 8
3     C 3 6 9
```

Combining this with the `row.names=FALSE` option in `write.table()` results in output with header names for all columns.

Answer (score 0):

I revised a simple function from @mnel, which adds flexibility by using connections. Here is the function:

```
my.write <- function(x, file, header, f = write.csv, ...){
# create and open the file connection
datafile <- file(file, open = 'wt')
# close on exit 
on.exit(close(datafile))
# if a header is defined, write it to the file (@CarlWitthoft's suggestion)
if(!missing(header)) {
writeLines(header,con=datafile, sep='\t')
writeLines('', con=datafile, sep='\n')
}
# write the file using the defined function and required addition arguments  
f(x, datafile,...)
}
```

You can specify the function to be 'write.table', 'write.csv', 'write.delim' etc.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add an ad-hoc solution that I haven't seen in this question or any linked questions already. Users may want to write a table with the formatting described above, but have a label present at the top of the first column (where the "" is in the accepted answer). The second answer presents a solution which works, but doesn't allow certain characters (and will replace " " characters with "."s, for example). This solution achieves same, but allows any character type permitted by R to be present in the header.

Starting with a matrix '`a`' which has the headers you'd like to use, less the header for the row_names column:

```
headers <- c("row_names", colnames(a)) #create headers, a character vector that will serve as the header line for your output file, "row_names" here can be replaced with a heading of your choice.
test <- data.frame("row_names"=rownames(a),a) #create data frame with "row_names" for top left position, and the existing row names as the first column. 
test <- as.matrix(rbind(headers, test)) #combine prepared headers with data frame above
write(t(test), "test_output.txt", sep = "\t", ncolumns = dim(test)[[2]]) #write output as a tab-separated file. object must be transposed for this command to produce a table in the expected orientation.
```