# How to append a whole dataframe to a CSV in R

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I can already append a row to a CSV using **cat** which makes that very easy:

```
  cat("my row, 1, 2, 3, 4", "mydf.csv",sep="\n", append=TRUE)
```

However as far as I know you cannot use cat with a whole dataframe (multiple columns and rows).

I am doing this because I am writing many DFs to a CSV and I want to append the multiple CSVs using **write.table**. The dataframes all have the same number of columns.

I thought about doing a loop over rows to write with cat but that doesn't sound like the best way - any one have good way of doing this in R?

Comment: Why not use `write.table`? It has an `append=TRUE` option and you can turn off the column names with `col.names=FALSE` for each data.frame after the first.

Comment: @MrFlick Or [fwrite( ... , append = TRUE)](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.12.2/topics/fwrite), which does both with a single option.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Ok so I realised that append=T does work with write.table - but write.table needs the sep switch to be used so this works:

```
write.table(myDF, "myDF.csv", sep = ",", col.names = !file.exists("myDF.csv"), append = T)
```

Comment: it does appends the columns but unfortunately it is adding one more row in the beginning and removing my last observation.

Comment: While writing into a csv file `write.table` shifts column names when you have rownames=TRUE, which results in your first column name set to the rownames column. You can avoid this problem by setting `col.names=NA`.  Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478352/write-table-writes-unwanted-leading-empty-column-to-header-when-has-rownames

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround (using cat) is that you transpose your data frame, then append a row containing only "\n" using rbind, then converting this data frame to a vector (it will have "\n" after every 'row') which will now show up in your csv file as a data frame.

Below an example:

```
df <- rbind(t(df),"\n")
cat(c("",df),sep=",",append=TRUE)
```

Note: my assumption is that you have opened a connection to a file using sink(*filepath/filename.csv*).

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough memory, the most efficient way is to bind them all together then write to file:

```
df <- cbind(df1, df2, df3)
write.csv(df, "spam.csv")
```

Otherwise, you can use the append argument in `write.csv`:

```
dfs <- c(df1, df2, df3)
for (df in dfs){
  write.csv(df, "eggs.csv", append = TRUE)
}
```

Comment: "These wrappers (`write.csv` and `write.csv2`) are deliberately inflexible: they are designed to ensure that the correct conventions are used to write a valid file. Attempts to change `append`, `col.names`, `sep`, `dec` or `qmethod` are ignored, with a warning."

Comment: Append has not worked with write.csv since 2010 apparently... not that it makes a lot of sense for R to warn you about deleting something after having deleted it irretrievably...who came up with that wonderful idea?