# i wanted to make the csv file as a database in R programming

Tags: r, database, csv

i wanted my csv file as a database which stores the data i enter whenever i run the program. it should keep on adding the names

```
add_prob<-function()
ad<-as.integer(readline("Enter how many probables, you are going to add: 
"))
df=data.frame(Reg=NA,Na=NA,Do=NA,Co=NA,E=NA)
for (i in 1:ad) {
dt<-Sys.Date()
Reg<-format(dt,format="%d %B % %Y")
Na<-readline("Enter the participant Name: ")
Do<-readline("Enter the domain he is working: ")
Co<-readline("Enter his mobile number: ")
E<-readline("Enter his E-mail ID: ")
df<-rbind(df,data.frame(Reg,Na,Do,Co,E))
}
write.csv(df, file="Training_Probables.csv", append=TRUE, row.names = 
FALSE, quote = TRUE)
df=df[-1,]
names(df)=c("Date","Name","Domain","Mobile No.", "E-Mail ID")
print(df)
write.csv(df, file="Training_Probables.csv", append=TRUE, row.names = 
FALSE, quote = TRUE)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append a whole dataframe to a CSV in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25436737/how-to-append-a-whole-dataframe-to-a-csv-in-r)

Comment: do you want to run this from the command line i.e. open up a terminal and do smth like   `Rscript add_user_todb.r 'John' 'IT' '000-111-222' 'john@it.com'` and have that r script automatically append this entry to a db?

Answer (score 0):

```
write.table(myDF, "myDF.csv", sep = ",", col.names = T, append = T)
```